# Angular, Get and show submit time after click submit button

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Is it possible to get the date and time when the user click the submit button in angular? For example i have a form with name and email input. When user done filling the input and click submit, the date and time will be showed to the table along with name and email. Here some snippets:

```js
//app.service.ts
insertData(data: App) {
  this.dataList.push({
    name: data.name,
    email: data.email,
  });
}

//app.component.ts
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  this.AppService.insertData(this.AppService.selectedData);
}
```

```html
<!--app.component.html-->
<form #dataForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(dataForm)">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="nama" #nama="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="AppService.selectedData.name"><br>

  <label>Email</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="AppService.selectedData.email"><br>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Time submitted</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of data">
    <td>data.name</td>
    <td>data.email</td>
    <td>Time submitted</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do :

```
this.dataList.push({
    nama: data.nama,
    email: data.email,
    time : new Date(),
  });
```

This will store the current time when you are inserting data and then use simply on the template side.

```
{{data.time | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: and to show it in table i just need to use `data.time` ?

Comment: Yes , you can use it like `{{data.time | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`.